# Convert CSV to a single Column in datagridview VB

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

as the title suggest i need to insert the CSV into a single column in DataTable.

```
CSV:
109-56-987-546-45-393
32-41-53-627-234-865-675
546-321-567-908-354-27-35
```

the datatable should be:

```
109
56
987
546
45
393
```

and so on..
this is my code.

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            Dim sr As New IO.StreamReader(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
            Dim dt As New DataTable

            dt.Columns.AddRange({New DataColumn(newline(0)),
                               New DataColumn(newline(1))})


            While (Not sr.EndOfStream)
                newline = sr.ReadLine.Split("-"c)
                Dim newrow As DataRow = dt.NewRow
                newrow.ItemArray = {newline(0), newline(1)}

                dt.Rows.Add(newrow)
            End While
            DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        End If
```

Comment: Do you only have one line in the file?

Comment: no sorry it's suppose to be 1-2-3-4 next line 5-6-7-8 and then next line 9-1-2-3 and so on... fixed my question. sorry about that

Comment: So three lines would translate to three columns then? Will cells in later rows be empty for columns where the corresponding line of text has fewer values? You really need to provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem.

Comment: in each line in the CSV there should be seven (7), ex. 1-2-3-4-5-6-7. i edit my question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone pointed out that i need to read this as a string then break it up to populate the DGV.

```
Dim data As String = File.ReadAllText("D:\Test Data\AAAData.csv")
Dim parts As String() = data.Split("-"c, vbLf)
Dim viewable = parts.[Select](Function(p) New With {Key.Value = p}).ToList()
dataGridView1.DataSource = viewable
```

Credits to OriginalGriff